# Is there a way to tell this script not to include the headers on the next line items?

Tags: vbscript

I have a script which allows me to grab certain machine info when a user runs the script, and the result gets written on a text file on a server share. The script works fine...however, I would like for it not to repeat the headers when the next user runs the script. I searched around the forums but couldn't find anything that would allow me to accomplish this. Apologies if my language is dull. I'm sure it's something pretty easy and would appreciate if someone could give me some pointers. I'm not a programmer but I'm very fascinated on writing scripts that makes my job easier.

Currently, this is how the result looks like.

> ```
> User Name, Host Name, Manufacturer, Serial Number, Operating System, Model  
> CA\username, NAPHX-C63E90K-L, LENOVO, PC63E90K, Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise   6.1.7601, 20AMS1UD00  
> User Name, Host Name, Manufacturer, Serial Number, Operating System, Model  
> CA\username, USAPHX-6GL4R7-L, LENOVO, PC6GL4R7, Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise  10.0.17134, 20FMS3XC00  
> User Name, Host Name, Manufacturer, Serial Number, Operating System, Model  
> CA\username, USAPHX-6KTBAY-L, LENOVO, PC6KTBAY, Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise  10.0.17134, 20EQS2NM00  
> User Name, Host Name, Manufacturer, Serial Number, Operating System, Model  
> CA\username, MEXMEC-6Z0A6U-L, LENOVO, PC6Z0A6U, Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise  10.0.17763, 20L8S6G20E
> ```

I want it to look like this instead.

> ```
> User Name, Host Name, Manufacturer, Serial Number, Operating System, Model  
> CA\username, NAPHX-C63E90K-L, LENOVO, PC63E90K, Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise   6.1.7601, 20AMS1UD00  
> CA\username, USAPHX-6GL4R7-L, LENOVO, PC6GL4R7, Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise  10.0.17134, 20FMS3XC00   
> CA\username, USAPHX-6KTBAY-L, LENOVO, PC6KTBAY, Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise  10.0.17134, 20EQS2NM00  
> CA\username, MEXMEC-6Z0A6U-L, LENOVO, PC6Z0A6U, Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise  10.0.17763, 20L8S6G20E
> ```

Here's a sample of my current script.

```
' On Error Resume Next

' Constants for FileSystemObject
Const FOR_READING = 1
Const FOR_WRITING = 2
Const FOR_APPENDING = 8

strFileOutput = "\\servershare\folder\info.txt"

' Create a Script Runtime FileSystemObject.
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Check to see if the output file exists. If so, open it for writing or appending.
' If not, create it and open it for writing.

If objFSO.FileExists(strFileOutput) Then
  Set objOutputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile (strFileOutput, FOR_APPENDING)
Else
  Set objOutputFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strFileOutput)
End If

If Err <> 0 Then
  Wscript.Echo "Unable to open " & strFileOutput & " for output."
  WScript.Quit
End If

'Create Headers for Host, Manufacturer, Serial Number
objOutputFile.Writeline "User Name, Host Name, Manufacturer, Serial Number, Operating System, Model"

strComputer = "."

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    Set colSettings = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")
        For Each objComputer in colSettings
        PCMfg = objComputer.Manufacturer
        PCName = objComputer.Name
        UserName = objComputer.UserName
        'Wscript.Echo "User: " & Manufacturer: " & PCMfg & VbCrLf & "PC Name: " & PCName
        NEXT

    Set colBIOS = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_BIOS")
        For each objBIOS in colBIOS
        SerNo = objBIOS.SerialNumber
        'Wscript.Echo "Serial Number: " & SerNo
        NEXT

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
        Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
        For Each objOperatingSystem in colOperatingSystems
        OS = objOperatingSystem.Caption & "  " & objOperatingSystem.Version
            'Wscript.Echo "Operating System: " & objOperatingSystem.Caption & "  " & objOperatingSystem.Version
        Next

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
        Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT Version FROM Win32_ComputerSystemProduct")
        For Each objItem in colItems
        Model = objItem.Name
            'Wscript.Echo "Model: " & objItem.Name
        Next 

        objOutputFile.Writeline Username & ", " & PCName & ", " & PCMfg & ", " & SerNo & ", " & OS & ", "& Model

    objOutputFile.Close

x=msgbox("Process is now complete. Thank you for your time!" ,0, "PC Info Complete")
```

Comment: What is the difference between the two outputs.

Comment: The first one has both headers and result on each line.
The second one, which is how I want it to come out. Only has the headers once and then the rest of the results are below it.

Comment: Why not just move the line that sets the headers to the file exists-check?

Answer (score 0):

Move the line that creates the headers to the file exists check, so that they are created only once per file:

```
If objFSO.FileExists(strFileOutput) Then
    Set objOutputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile (strFileOutput, FOR_APPENDING)
Else
Set objOutputFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strFileOutput)
    'moved this line
    'Create Headers for Host, Manufacturer, Serial Number
    objOutputFile.Writeline "User Name, Host Name, Manufacturer, Serial Number, Operating System, Model"
End If
```